# How can I programmatically change Windows Shell settings using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-shell

Using PowerShell, I can do:

```
$shell = new-object -com Shell.Application
$shell.GetSetting(0x2)
```

Which correctly returns whether the shell shows extensions for known file types.

Note: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg537739(v=VS.85).aspx for a list of flag values that can be passed to GetSetting.

**Question**: I can *get* the values, but how would I *change* them? I looked through the [Shell object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521729%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but I'm just not seeing it a matching method to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exact answer, but you can edit registry?

For example:

```
set-itemproperty -Name HideFileExt -Value 0 -path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
```